# Android - Gradle Cannot get property 'username' on null object

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I use own repository of my company and I get the repository credentials from the .m2/settings.xml.
I had been doing well until the last update of Android Studio and Gradle plugin (AS 0.8.14, Gradle 0.13.2). Since I have updated them, I'm getting the following "Gradle project sync" error:

```
Error;(57,0) Cannot get property 'username' on null object
```

The problem is in here:

```
    allprojects {
       group 'com.tempos21.android.commons'
       repositories { // repositories needed in project
            mavenCentral() // maven central repository
            maven{ // another repository. Our nexus
                credentials {
                   def credentials = getCredentials("internal")
                   username = credentials["username"]
                   password = credentials["password"]
                }
                url "https://nexus1.tempos21.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases" // url of our nexus repository
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the "credentials" object is null in the next line (it wasn't null before the update). The method getCredentials is:

```
// get repository credentials from .m2/settings.xml
def getCredentials(server) {
    def entries = getMavenSettingsCredentials()
    for (entry in entries) {
        if ( entry."id".text() == server ) {
            return [username: entry.username.text(), password: entry.password.text()]
        }
    }
}
```

And the getMavenSettingsCredentials is:

```
// read .m2/settings.xml
def getMavenSettingsCredentials() {
    String userHome = System.getProperty( "user.home" );
    File mavenSettings = new File(userHome, ".m2/settings.xml")
    def xmlSlurper = new XmlSlurper()
    def output = xmlSlurper.parse(mavenSettings)
    return output."servers"."server"
}
```

Does anyone know if there has been any change in the last updates that would cause this error in my gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, it was my fault. I didn't remember that I changed my settings.xml for doing a test, which didn't have the own repository credentials.... So, if someone has a similar problem, please check your settings.xml file :p